# Datatables server side ajax and sAjaxSource have different request parameter

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I've made a datatable with server-side processing using **sAjaxSource** parameter.

```
$('#tbl-kamus').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": srcUri ,
    ...
```

And when it made a request to server, it sends GET data with these parameter:

```
sEcho: 1
iColumns: 4
sColumns: ,,,,,,
iDisplayStart: 0
iDisplayLength: 30
mDataProp_0: 0
sSearch_0: 
bRegex_0: false
bSearchable_0: true
bSortable_0: false
mDataProp_1: 1
sSearch_1: 
bRegex_1: false
bSearchable_1: true
bSortable_1: true
mDataProp_2: 2
sSearch_2: 
bRegex_2: false
bSearchable_2: true
bSortable_2: true
mDataProp_3: 3
sSearch_3: 
bRegex_3: false
bSearchable_3: true
bSortable_3: false
sSearch: 
bRegex: false
iSortCol_0: 1
sSortDir_0: desc
iSortCol_1: 2
sSortDir_1: desc
iSortingCols: 2
```

and use those GET parameter in the php to process the request.
then i need to add more parameter to the request, so i change the option into

```
$('#tbl-kamus').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "ajax": {
         "url": srcUri,
         "data": {
         "user_id": userID
    }
    ...
```

And the whole request parameter changed into array-like thing:

```
draw: 1
columns[0][data]: 0
columns[0][name]: 
columns[0][searchable]: true
columns[0][orderable]: false
columns[0][search][value]: 
columns[0][search][regex]: false
columns[1][data]: 1
columns[1][name]: 
columns[1][searchable]: true
columns[1][orderable]: true
columns[1][search][value]: 
columns[1][search][regex]: false
columns[2][data]: 2
columns[2][name]: 
columns[2][searchable]: true
columns[2][orderable]: true
columns[2][search][value]: 
columns[2][search][regex]: false
columns[3][data]: 3
columns[3][name]: 
columns[3][searchable]: true
columns[3][orderable]: false
columns[3][search][value]: 
columns[3][search][regex]: false
order[0][column]: 1
order[0][dir]: desc
order[1][column]: 2
order[1][dir]: desc
start: 0
length: 30
search[value]: 
search[regex]: false
user_id: 2
```

so i have to change my server-side script to accomodate that, which i avoid. Then as a workaround, i keep using sAjaxSource and append the user_id into the url like :

```
"sAjaxSource":srcUri+"?user_id="+userID+"&",
```

what bothers me is why do they have different request parameters format. Can anyone please explain why are they different and what are the significance between each method?

**EDIT:**

I am sorry, perhaps my explanation wasn't quite clear. What i am asking here is not how to pass an argument in datatable ajax. Although i'm so grateful for the mention about fnServerParams, which is what i need atm.

What i am asking here is why are the request parameter between sAjaxSource and ajax so different?
or perhaps both method have different purposes?
i can't seem to find about it in the documentation.

Comment: Use `fnServerParams` instead of adding them programmatically.  You really cant avoid the array style, since that is how DT passes back for example sorting on a certian column. It is all well documented at **https://datatables.net/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Legacy):

> Older versions of DataTables (1.9-) used a different set of parameters
>   to send and receive from the server. As such scripts which are written
>   for DataTables 1.10+ will not be able to function with DataTables
>   1.9-. However, DataTables 1.10 does have a compatibility mode for scripts written for 1.9-. This compatibility mode is triggered by use
>   of the old **sAjaxSource** parameter (rather than the new ajax parameter)
>   or by setting $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;

You're triggering compatibility mode when you use sAjaxSource with DataTables (1.10+) which sends and receives different set of parameters than legacy DataTables (1.9-).

[Server Side Example with Custom HTTP variables - Legacy](http://legacy.datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)

[Server Side Example with Custom HTTP variables](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)

Comment: Goodness gracious! It was right there on the document all along, I'm must be blind. Thanks jeetaz

Comment: BTW, I preferred to use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;` along with `ajax: { ... }` till the time I update my server side code to parse new format instead of legacy. That way, I'm all set on the front-end for the update, only have to get rid of `$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;`. Gratitude to you my friend

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr - Glad it helped! (y)